# How to return input JSON with one changed property in JQ

Tags: json, jq, edit

I am trying to make JQ return an output that's nearly identical to the input, only chaing one property whose sibling matches a string.

Say an input of:

```json
{
  "version": 3,
  "projects": [
    {
      "name": "project1",
      "autoplan": { "enabled": false }
    },
    {
      "name": "project2",
      "autoplan": { "enabled": false }
    }
  ],
  "workflows": {}
}
```

I've gotten close with the following:

```bash
jq '.projects[] | select(.name == "project1").autoplan.enabled |= true'
```

But the problem is this just returns the projects individually (and without other root properties), like so:

```json
{
  "name": "project1",
  "autoplan": { "enabled": true }
}
{
  "name": "project2",
  "autoplan": { "enabled": false }
}
```

How can I return the data how it was structured originally, but with my changed value? I would rather not have to reassemble an array with the returned items and manually specify each original property.

I am looking for the following:

```json
{
  "version": 3,
  "projects": [
    {
      "name": "project1",
      "autoplan": { "enabled": true }
    },
    {
      "name": "project2",
      "autoplan": { "enabled": false }
    }
  ],
  "workflows": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the whole object with the updated value

```
(.projects[] | select(.name == "project1").autoplan.enabled) |= true
```

The `()` around the [`select()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)) makes the [`|=`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Update-assignment:%7C=) not update the value of the complete object, rather just the selected one

#### [Try it online](https://jqplay.org/s/t4X1NL8vwLr)

Comment: Amazing! Had seen the `()` in jq before but never learned its meaning. Thanks!